# Laravel Mix my javascript code is not running

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

I'm using `Laravel` facing a problem when compiling assets. By default laravel provides a wrapper around webpack which is `laravel-mix`, `laravel-mix` using file called `webpack.mix.js`, and by using `npm run dev` command, `laravel-mix`compile all `js` files into one webpack bundle `js` file.

Code of webpack.mix.js:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

I have a `Main.js` file which has some `jquery` code.

Main.js:

```
;( function( $, window, document, undefined ) {

    'use strict';
    $(window).on('load', function() {
        alert('ready');
    });
 }
)( jQuery, window, document );
```

My directory structure is something like this

```
resources\assets\js

app.js
bootstrap.js
Main.js
```

Code of app.js:

```
require('./bootstrap');
```

Code of bootstrap.js:

```
try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');// jquery
    require('bootstrap');// bootstrap framework js
    require('./Main'); // Main.js


} catch (e) {
}
```

When i type command `npm run dev` all assets are compile into one file then why my `Main.js` jquery code which is just an alert popup doesn't execute on the page.

But when i change order of the `bootstrap.js` file into something like this then my `Main.js` code is execute.

```
try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');// jquery
    require('./Main'); // Main.js
    require('bootstrap');// bootstrap framework js



} catch (e) {
}
```

Why this thing is happening. Does conflict happen between `bootstrap framework js` file and `Main.js` file.

Comment: Can you provide your browser console when your code doesn't execute?

Comment: @nmfzone There is not any error comes, but when i load my page my `Main.js` script is not executed

Answer (score 7):

Replying to the tldr in the comments:

> There is not any error comes, but when i load my page my Main.js script is not executed

I had this same issue and including the `manifest.js` and `vendor.js` solved these issues:

```html
<script src="{{ mix('js/manifest.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ mix('js/vendor.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! Tried to solve a similar problem for 2 hours. Now it is fixed. Did not know that .extract() is applied to every js you compile with mix!

Comment: Yes it is applied to every js file. It looks at all the dependencies of all included js files and then determines what should be included in the `vendor.js`. And the 'start script' (the one that calls the bundled JavaScript files that are created from the entrypoints) is the `manifest.js`, so it should be included as well.